# Try put on hold a call and then retrieve that

Tags: twilio

How can put on hold a live call?

And respect that,

I'm using Javascript SDK.

How can put on hold a live call with Twilio.Device or Twilio.Comunication?

For example:

- Customer phones to Company.
- Agent of Company response the call
- Agent and Customer are Speaking
- Agent puts on hold a call
- Customer listen a sound
- Agent is joins again on the call to continue speaking
- The call ending

I hope I've explained myself well

Sorry for my english!

Thanks

Comment: Could show us some code? I mean - how did you attempt to approach the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

There is no way to put a call "on hold" directly from the Javascript SDK.  What you could do is redirect the ongoing call to a new set of TwiML which provides an "on hold" experience like playing an audio file, or putting the call into a Queue.

We have a Twimlet that provides the ability to loop over an audio file as a "hold" experience here:

https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/holdmusic

As an example doing this, you would use some TwiML that looks something like this:

```
<Response>
    <Say> Thank you for calling, a representative will be with you shortly</Say>
   <Play loop="100">http://www.mydomain.foo/hold-music.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

This would loop indefinitely.  To move the caller back out of hold, you use the REST API to redirect the call:

```
POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Account/{YourAccountSid}/Calls/{WaitingCallersCallSid}
CurrentUrl=http://www.example.com/dial-representitive
```

Those samples contain code from a blog post that walks you through this scenario:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/09/call-queueing-putting-callers-on-hold-calll-redirect-new-url-new-feature.html

Hope that helps.